# If a spell is cast using a higher-level spell slot, can it be overchanneled by an Evocation wizard?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, wizard, spell-slots

If my level 14 Evocation wizard were to cast a [*fireball*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fireball) using a seventh level spell slot, would he be able to maximise the damage with overchannel despite the overchannel feature indicating that the spell must be below 5th level?

> When you cast a wizard spell of 5th level or lower that deals damage, you can deal maximum damage with this spell.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No.

> When a spellcaster casts a spell using a slot that is of a higher level for that casting, the spell assumes the higher level for that casting. (PHB. p 201)

Therefore when you do this, the fireball is for all intents and purposes a seventh level spell and is eligible/ineligible for various add-on effects based on that.

Comment: For what it's worth, [Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/598726877730066432) agrees with this: *"[Fireball upcast to 7th level] won't work [with overchannel], since that fireball is 7th level. The level of a spell matches the level of the slot used to cast it (PH, 201)."*